# Performance Progress Bar Not Getting Visible

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am using performance progress bar in my application. What I am doing is making progress bar visiblity to Visible before starting some lengthy operation and collapsing it when operation completed. But It is not visible before starting that operation.
Here is my code

```
  ucSearch.prograssBarCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        var obj = wb1.InvokeScript("SearchText", ucSearch.txtSearch.Text.Trim());
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BookChapter>>(obj.ToString());
        if (result.Count == 0)
        {
            ucSearch.txtBlMessage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            ucSearch.lstBxResults.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            ucSearch.txtBlMessage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            ucSearch.lstBxResults.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }

        ucSearch.lstBxResults.DataContext = null;
        ucSearch.lstBxResults.DataContext = result;
        ucSearch.prograssBarCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I want to ask why it is not visible??

Comment: Tag says Windows Phone 7. Are you by any chance building a Windows Phone 8 application? The toolkit `PerformanceProgressBar` will not be visible in those projects.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the `IsEnabled` and `IsIndeterminate` properties of the progress bar are `true`.